# Group by is null or not?

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird

I want to count how many records in Firebird database have timestamp field null or not null. How to do it?

Something like this:

```
select RECORD_TYPE, count(*), (MY_TIMESTAMP IS NULL) from MY_TABLE 
group by RECORD_TYPE, (MY_TIMESTAMP IS NULL)
```

I'm using Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can output a single record with two columns,

```
SELECT  COUNT(MY_TIMESTAMP) AS TOTAL_NOTNULL,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN MY_TIMESTAMP IS NULL THEN 1 END) TOTAL_NULL
FROM    MY_TABLE
```

Comment: this output will look like the result on this demo http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1de18/1

Comment: did you try to run it on your records?

Comment: Yes, however I ended up to sligthly different query and using IIF after getting idea from your query.